# Single Linked List in C value of parameter

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am a bit novice in this. Just wanted to ask why isnt the value of start not changing but how is the value of p changing during each successive call?

The code goes like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int elt;
    struct Node *next;
} node;

void insert (int, node *);
void delete (int, node *);
void print (node *);
int find (int, node *);
void insertp (int, node *);
node *findp (int, node *);

main ()
{
    node *start, *temp;
    node *q;
    start = (node *) malloc (sizeof (node));
    temp = start;
    temp->next = NULL;
    printf ("Start before while : %d \n", start);
    printf ("Start is pointing to : %d \n", start->next);
    int choice;
    while (1) {
        printf
            ("1.Insert \n2.Display \n3.Find \n4.Insert at given position \n5.Delete \n");
        scanf ("%d", &choice);
        if (choice == 1) {
            int data;
            scanf ("%d", &data);
            insert (data, start);
            printf ("Start inside while : %d \n", start);
        }
        if (choice == 2) {
            print (start->next);
            printf ("\n");
        }
        if (choice == 3) {
            int fin;
            scanf ("%d", &fin);
            if (find (fin, start) == 1)
                printf ("Found \n");
            else
                printf ("Not Found \n");
        }
        if (choice == 4) {
            int ins;
            scanf ("%d", &ins);
            int x;
            scanf ("%d", &x);
            q = findp (x, start);
            insertp (ins, q);
        }
    }
}

void insert (int x, node * p)
{
    while (p->next != NULL)
        p = p->next;
    p->next = (node *) malloc (sizeof (node));
    p = p->next;
    p->elt = x;
    p->next = NULL;
    printf ("P : %d \n", p);
}

void print (node * q)
{
    if (q == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    printf ("%d ", q->elt);
    print (q->next);
}

int find (int x, node * p)
{
    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p->elt == x)
            return 1;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

void insertp (int x, node * p)
{
    node *tmpcell = (node *) malloc (sizeof (node));
    tmpcell->elt = x;
    tmpcell->next = p->next;
    p->next = tmpcell;
}

node *findp (int x, node * p)
{
    while (p != NULL && p->elt != x)
        p = p->next;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Now.. I've added a basic formatting to your question. fix the indentation yourself..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  More urgently, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Your problem is almost certainly the standard one that you either need to pass a pointer to a pointer into your `insert*()` functions, or you need to return a pointer from the functions — your function cannot modify the value in the calling function directly as written.  There are many, many questions on SO where this is the problem.  Few of them have high marks because the question is so frequent.

Comment: You have initialized start by "start = (node *) malloc (sizeof (node));", and there is no statement in the loop where start is changed, so you have not changed start in successive calls, so how it will change?

Answer (score 0):

For the value of start to change you will have to pass in the address of start to the insert function and modify it to be like the following. Only then will the value of start change upon every insert.

```
void insert(int x,node **p)
{
   while((*p)->next!=NULL)
      (*p)=(*p)->next;
     (*p)->next=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
     (*p)=(*p)->next;
     (*p)->elt=x;
     (*p)->next=NULL;
    printf("P : %d \n",p); 
}
```